# $S=\{a\in G:f(x)=f(ax)\; \forall x\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group and $f:G\rightarrow G$ a function. Let $S=\{a\in G:f(x)=f(ax)\; \forall x\in G\}$. Prove that $S$ is a subgroup of $G$.

This is my first encounter with functions in this topic. Any hints on where to begin in order to show $S$ is closed on products and inverses?

My attempt: (I feel like this is an invalid proof, but it's all I can think of. Please leave feedback.)

Let $a,b\in G$. This means that $ab\in G$. Since $f:G\rightarrow G$, and $ab\in G$, then $f(x) = f([ab]x)$. So $ab\in S$.

$\therefore S$ is closed on products.

I don't know where to start in proving it for inverses.

Any hints? (No full solutions, please)

Thank you.

Comment: You "proved" that if a and b are in G then (ab) is in S??? This cannot be true. Your actual task (regarding the stability by product) is to show that if a and b are in S then (ab) is in S.

Comment: The question you put on top says "Prove that $S$ is a *subset* of $G$". If you think it should be *subgroup*, please change that.

Comment: Did--yes, I see that mistake now. I cannot figure out how to show that $f(x)=f(ax)=f(bx)$ implies $f(x)=f(abx)$. And I corrected the typo

Comment: Patrick: the assumption is that $f(bx)=f(x)$ for ALL $x\in G$. Ditto for $f(ax)=f(x)$. What happens if you plug in $x=by$?

Comment: See the hint by @Seirios for your previous question.

Comment: Jyrki: I tried that but I struggled because I could only show that $f(x)=f(ax)=f(aby)$. Is this valid? Can I just say that this works since $x,y\in G $?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

- For closure under products, see Jyrki Lahtonen's hint [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907538/s-a-in-gfx-fax-forall-x-in-g-is-a-subgroup-of-g#comment1872604_907538).
- For closure under inverses, suppose that $a \in S$ so that for any $y \in G$, we have that $f(y) = f(ay)$. We want to show that $a^{-1} \in S$. To this end, choose any $x \in G$. In terms of $x$, what do you think that we should set $y$ to be in order to conclude that $f(x) = f(a^{-1}x)$?
- To complete the subgroup test, don't forget to show that $S$ is nonempty!